# Is SQL server 2008 storing uf8

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, unicode, utf-8

I have a java servlet that is using utf8. I have entered numerous characters (chinese traditional, russian, etc) and they seem to be stored in and retreived from sql server 2008 fine. Does sql server 2008 handle utf8 encoded strings? If not, why no problems, yet.

```
    psmt.setString(7, myString); //myString is UTF8 encoded
    psmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Java uses internally Unicode (to hold all scripts), but that is irrelevant. The database driver converts the String to some bytes using the appropriate encoding. The column must be able to hold some Unicode encoding like UTF-8 or UTF-16LE, UCS-2. Like `NTEXT`. The transport by the driver may need Unicode too `jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.01:1433;databaseName=MYDB;characterEncoding=UTF-8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your string is actually UTF-16-encoded - it's a Java string, and Java strings are sequences of UTF-16 code units.

It (mostly) doesn't matter how SQL server stores the value internally, so long as it can represent the same character repertoire. Your SQL schema should determine what values can be stored - *how* they're stored is irrelevant.

There are potentially many important encodings here:

- The encoding you use when you present data from your app, e.g. via HTML
- The encoding used internally by Java (UTF-16, as least as it's exposed by the language)
- The encoding used to transfer data to the database (which is under the control of the database driver; this may or may not need to be configured)
- The encoding used to store the data within the database

All of these can be different - so long as they can store the same set of characters. So while the bytes used to represent ☃ (U+2603, Unicode Snowman) will be different when it's encoded in UTF-8 and UTF-16, so long as it *can* be encoded (and is encoded properly), that's all that matters.

Now there are some cases where the abstraction falls down, of course - if you ask for the length of a string in Java with the `String.length()`, that's the length in UTF-16 code units, not in Unicode characters. Similarly, if you've got SQL fields which are limited to a particular length, you should pay careful attention to what those units are. (I don't know offhand for SQL Server 2008, but I've seen databases where that's in terms of UTF-16 code units, and others where it's in terms of bytes required in the UTF-8 encoding.) So in that sort of situation, the difference can be important - but the general "Can I store my data?" question doesn't require the encodings to be the same.

Comment: UTF 16. Thanks... The reason I was pressing utf8 was the following in my code=> myString = new String(myReqParam.getBytes(ISO, UTF8));

Comment: @Paul: Right - it's hard to tell exactly what that line of code is doing without knowing about `myReqParam` etc, but I *strongly* suspect you're taking UTF-8-encoded data and then decoding it using the platform default encoding, which is a good way to lose data. Don't do that.

Comment: @Paul: Just because it hasn't broken yet doesn't mean the code isn't a bug waiting to happen. You should look at that line *very* carefully. As for what SQL server is using - you almost certainly need to check your schema carefully, as well as any collation settings.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
This is from my take on answers on StackOverflow...
request.getParameter URLDecodes() the string and interprets it as iso-8859-1 - whatever the URIEncoding is set to in the server.xml. to correct use the following:
new String(request.getParameter("name").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8") 
or change server.xml file.
jsp page is utf8, comes through servlet, the getparameter uses iso decoding since server.xml states as such and munges the getParameter, so re-interpret the bytes with the correct encoding.

Comment: @Paul: that code looks better - but that's not what your first comment said. It's still *horribly* dodgy though. Anything trying to "fix" broken encoding is asking for trouble, IMO.

Comment: Yes, trying to work around a previous bad decode step after the fact is normally the wrong thing; instead one should fix it where the decode originally happens. Unfortunately this is unreasonably difficult to do reliably in the case of the ISO-8859-1 input decoder in Java Servlet, so the getBytes-String dance is understandable. But yes, the `new String` without encoding parameter is using the server's default encoding which is invariably the wrong thing to do.